# Does cloud foundry provide services for archiving logs on other cloud storages like Amazon S3

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to find a way to archive application logs of app deployed on Cloud Foundry to an external cloud storage like amazon s3.

Is there a service within cloud foundry that caters for such requirement? If not, is there any third party utility providing the same?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Thanks,
Kinjal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there is no such thing, as far as I know. However, via the Cloud Foundry API you have full access to all files deployed as part of an application, including the logs. This means building an application that could transfer all those files to S3 at a regular interval would be fairly trivial.

Comment: As I think this is going to be something people might want I decide to build a small Ruby app that does exactly that! https://github.com/danhigham/log_squirrel